# How do I write a method which returns characters of a string?

Tags: java

How would I write a method using a substring which returns the first 10 characters of a string?
This is what I have so far but I keep getting an error message saying I need a return statement.

```
public String firstTen(String number) {
    number.substring(0, 10);

    System.out.println(number);
```

Comment: `return number.substring(0, 10);`

Comment: you've declared that function will return String but you haven't returned in your function
Code should be like this

public String firstTen(String number) {
  return number.substring(0, 10);
}

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you need to return in your method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(firstTen("Hello World Java"));
}

public static String firstTen(String number) {
    return number.substring(0, 10);
}
```

if the string length is less then 10 then it will cause error to prevent from it you can check it as below:

```
public static String firstTen(String number) {
    return number.length() > 10 ? number.substring(0, 10) : number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String firstTen(String number) {
return  number.substring (0,10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the result of `substring`. If it is possible for the `String` to be less than 10 characters, you may also want the end index to be the minimum of 10 and the length of the String to avoid a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public String firstTen(String number) {
   return number.substring (0, Math.min(10, number.length()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your answear

```java
public String firstTen(String number)
{
    return number.substring(0, 10);
    
}
```

Comment: you code has error, because you defined a return type of String for your `firstTen` method but nothing is return in method body.